# Why didn't Kenjirou Hata continue Ad Astra Per Aspera?

Tags: ad-astra-per-aspera

The manga [Ad Astra Per Aspera](https://myanimelist.net/manga/92627/Ad_Astra_Per_Aspera) is currently on hiatus. The author, Kenjirou Hata, according to the internet (I forgot the source), stopped working on *Ad Astra  Per Aspera* because he wanted to focus on *Hayate No Gotoku*.

Then why didn't Kenjirou Hata continue Ad Astra Per Aspera, even after he just finished his other work [Hayate no Gotoku](https://myanimelist.net/manga/696/Hayate_no_Gotoku) in April?

**UPDATE**

I read this news: [Hayate's Author Has Already Drawn 6 Chapters of New Manga Series](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2017-10-20/hayate-the-combat-butler-hata-has-already-drawn-6-chapters-of-new-manga-series/.122944). Does anyone know what that new manga series he's working on would be? Is it possible that it is *Ad Astra Per Aspera*?

**UPDATE 05/11/2018**

The manga that been talked about on this [article](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2017-10-20/hayate-the-combat-butler-hata-has-already-drawn-6-chapters-of-new-manga-series/.122944) is [*Tonikaku Kawaii*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/112589/Tonikaku_Kawaii) a new manga series by Hata kenjirou on Shounen Sunday Magazine, that was first published on Feb 14, 2018. The manga still on going.

[image: Ad Astra Per Aspera]

Comment: do we have to use the author name as a tag ?

Comment: I think this question only for Ad Astra Per Aspera, unless you also want to know what happen to the author

Comment: yeah, i want to know what happen to the author @Darjeeling, i guess

Comment: Regarding "new manga series", it seems it's about [*Tonikaku Kawaii*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/112589/Tonikaku_Kawaii)